Why does Swagger duplicate my documentation in endpoints using {format}?
I am creating documentation with Swagger in a Django project, I don't understand why it duplicates some endpoints by adding {format} at first sight they are the same endpoints:

for example GET /profile/v1/{id} there is also a version with {format}
settings.py:
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ),
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
    ]
}


on views.py:
class ProfileDetailView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [FullProfilePermissionGroup]

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        operation_description="Retrieve a single profile by ID.",
        responses={
            200: openapi.Response(
                description="Profile retrieved successfully", schema=ProfileSerializer
            ),
            404: openapi.Response(description="Profile not found"),
        },
        produces=["application/json"]
    )
    def get(self, request, pk):
        profile = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile)
        return Response(serializer.data)

It is not a blocking problem, but I would like to eliminate it, can you help me? Thanks
